# Puzzling Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

[image: A T-SHIRT!]

T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!

[image: STICKERS!]

STICKERS!!!!!!!

I'll be reaching out to you shortly with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

**Update 10/17/2016:** The swag is shipped out of the warehouse! Enjoy!

Comment: Big smile.  This is a great surprise!

Comment: I feel so bad for [rand al'thor](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) and the 73th place :P

Comment: What about the users(in top 72) who are not active at all :-?

Comment: Right,... Whatever got him temporarilly suspended, [rand al'thor](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) surely contributed a lot to the success of this site (and heated discussions).

Comment: @LuxxMiner Good point, we don't usually have high-rep suspended users when we run these, but I've put his name into the list manually.

Comment: @ABcDexter Well, they *have* been active and therefore earned their place, I think. I'm more worried about "cheap rep" outweighting "quality rep", but in the end: It's a *gift*, so no questions asked! (Oh, and if they are very inactive *now*, they will miss out anyway ;c))

Comment: I want that tee-shirt O:) and the stickers too ^_^

Comment: Cool, my niece and nephew always love more stickers :D

Comment: Stickers are love, stickers are life.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks :)

Comment: I feel bad for the user in 73rd place

Comment: I've been waiting for this. The only reason I signup for SE beta websites is to earn enough fake internet points until graduation so I can get a free t-shirt and avoid buying t-shirts. It's totally worth it.

Comment: I just got an email about this - awesome! Glad my hard work has finally paid off ;)

Comment: T-shirts? How Awesome! Nice Keepsakes, Sir!

Comment: :O I'm in the list! This is the first time I've ever won anything! I'd like to thank my mother, and the moderators, and my pet turtle

Comment: @animuson I see the top users are chosen on the basis of rep - quite capitalistic I must say. You should, in my opinion, also consider those who have been here for a long time and those who gave a lot of rep to the community to make it grow - which is also capitalistic. The only difference is I would get a shirt, too :D

Comment: It feels too good to be on the second from the last on that list.

Comment: @Avigrail That's a great point, we do ignore rep lost to bounties and it would be nice to include that into our selection process somehow, but it'd also make it harder to audit. It's very easy to just say "everyone on the first 2 pages" - there's a definitive cut-off and it's easy to see where you needed to be. Including users from other pages based on information not easily accessible on-site would make things rather confusing. Not to say we'll never do it, but it's something to think about. Also of note, adding in the bounties you've given away wouldn't actually put you in the top 72 here.

Comment: @animuson It's honorable you really looked it all up. But I wasn't completely serious here - I figured I'd not make it since I've never been the grinder type ;)

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat hey its me ur brother

Comment: If there was a Stack Exchange gift shop, I'd surely buy that T-shirt.

Comment: @Peanut wouldn't we alll?

Comment: @fi12 True, as Stack Exchange is love, Stack Exchange is life.

Comment: I thought the box would at least have some puzzles to be solved that would get you to the next location, where in turns you will get more clues in envelopes, and ... Oh, this is a prize, not a treasure hunt, right. haha

Comment: Will there be a notification/announcement when the shirts are sent out? I imagine it can take a while for internation shipping, but I'd be curious ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest Yes, I'll update this post when I get the notification that the items have shipped (they usually send me one). But as an update, this was just sent to the warehouse 6 days ago. Once that happens, I don't get updates on its progress until it actually ships out (but part of that process is interacting with the designers so the items can actually be *made* - it's not ready to go when they receive the list).

Comment: @animuson Any progress? Apologies for being impatient!

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat The proofs for this were approved last week. It should be in the printing process now.

Comment: @animuson Do we not get emailed a tracking reference code this time? Last time I got SE swag, I could track it online almost to the door. It's quite nice to know when to expect it, especially if it's going to be a signed-for delivery again.

Comment: @randal'thor No, we do not receive tracking information for bulk shipments like this. We only receive that information when we send individual shipments.

Comment: @animuson I recently bought a new house and will be moving in the first week of november.  Is it too late to change my shipping address?

Comment: Cheers from Germany.
The Swag arrived today.

Comment: Same here. Thanks!

Comment: Mine too - no need to change my address.

Comment: my swag hasn't arrived yet. Is there any chance of its arrival. :(

Answer (score 11):

Received my shirt/stickers late last week, and I have since realised that:

1. This post is going to be left, just hanging here indefinitely, with no "answer"
2. It feels weird to get stuff for free without actually acknowledging it

So, on behalf of Puzzling.SE:

> **Thanks to the Stack Overflow team for creating the platform that has allowed this community to thrive**, even if we are the black sheep of the family and are constantly breaking the conventions upon which the whole network was created.

And, on behalf of the chosen 72:

> **Thanks for the swag!**

---

[image: Nice shirt!]
<sup>*Artist's impression (stickers not to scale).*</sup>

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: Can I just say, you handsome devil :-P (Also, grrr, why haven't I got my swag yet?)

Comment: @randal'thor - Thanks. I've been working out. :) (and re: your swag, not sure where it shipped from, but I would've thought it'd reach you before me...)

Comment: ohh..so that's that PC you use to design your puzzles. :-p

Comment: Finally feel I can upvote this answer now that mine has also arrived. Thanks to @animuson and SE!