# Page not found puzzle

Tags: feature-request

Is the image below a puzzle? It's to hard for me in that case!

[image]

If it is not; I think it should be. And I think it should be a community contest to create a visually as interesting piece which is at the same time a hidden puzzle. I like the image, it's quite intriguing, it even got a key. But it's aesthetic appeal makes me think it just there for show and not an actual puzzle.

Comment: There are plenty of visually appealing puzzles, just look on main >_>. And no that's not a hidden puzzle

Answer (score 1):

**No, the 404 page isn't a puzzle.**

It's just part of the overall [Puzzling SE site design](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4630/5373). We have a very similar thing on the [T-shirts we were sent](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5162/5373) when the site graduated.

As for creating a visually interesting piece which is also a puzzle, that does sound like a nice idea for a community contest on the main site. Perhaps you could propose something along these lines for a [topic challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)? You'll have stiff competition though - there are already some truly *excellent* [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) puzzles on this site, from creative geniuses such as [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja), [Avigrail](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5106/avigrail), and [Bmyguest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest).