# Does Puzzling SE still send Swag?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through the questions on non-meta PSE and one question reminded me that puzzling gives Swag. So I was wondering if they still do this.

I looked at [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/puzzling-stack-exchange-top-user-swag) Meta PSE post that talks about the conditions for 2016, so I am wondering are the condition the same for 2018? If so how do I get some?

Comment: That wasn't "the conditions for 2016", that was the conditions at **site graduation**, which only happens once.

Answer (score 3):

This was a one-time thing and has not been repeated.

Right now the only known ways to get sweet sweet PSE swag are:

- become a Moderator.
  <sup>Note this *may* require convincing an existing Mod to step down, perhaps using poison or violence, or by [kidnapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2FAO.png)</sup>
- reach 100k rep.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: Note that SE also sometimes provides swag to be used as rewards for site-sponsored contests (if we chose to do something like that).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain  Shhhhh! We were saving that for the "top four flags-handled in 2018Q2" contest.

Comment: Your "kidnapping" link was disappointing, given how many *actual* puzzles on the site have involved kidnapping mods (I can think of three off the top of my head).

Comment: @Randal'Thor The great thing about SE is ... you can edit other people's answers, too. :)